# Visual Studio Code Outline view is empty for Javascript file

Tags: visual-studio-code

After update to v.1.43.1 (MacOS Catalina) the Outline view is empty for any Javascript file, it always displays just the "default" line. I have not modified any settings. Any idea what I could have broken, please?

Comment: Is everything ok for other file types in your project? What is the version of JS you're on? You can find it in the bottom-left part of the screen. It is selectable, which means you can switch to a different version. Also, many development tools depend on Comand Line Tools kit in OSX, and you need to reinstall it each time you update your OS version. Have you tried `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: I've done xcode-select --install, it's no better. I cannot find Javascript version in the bottom-left part of the screen. I've also tried to reinstall Code, still no good. Maybe I need to remove also some hidden settings to be sure new installation fixes the problem?